# Android Http connection not working

Tags: android, http, post, get

I'm learning to do the HTTP Client connections in Android for my app and I'm having issues.  I followed along a tutorial at the New Boston letter for letter yet still it did not appear to work.  I can see in my status bar at the top of my device that it is going out to get data but nothing is coming back.

Ideally at this point I need to connect to the api.php file on the server and send it a login command (and later a post command using the key that the login command returns).

I know I have to build a URI to pass to the HttpPost but at that point I'm lost...the example app that I ran does not return the data like it did in the tutorial.

I have the manifest set up to allow INTERNET access.

Here is the code from the tutorial (it uses an HttpGet but I can translate to the HttpPost once I figure out why it wouldn't be working).

```
public String getInternetData() throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = "did this work";
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://www.longship.ca");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                .getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
                return data;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    }

}
```

I have added the code from the main java file like I stated in my comments.  The class being called is called "GetMethodEx.java".

public class HttpTest extends Activity {

```
TextView tvResponse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webtest);
    tvResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
    GetMethodEx gme = new GetMethodEx();
    String returned;
    try {
        tvResponse.setText("Getting Data");
        returned = gme.getInternetData();

        tvResponse.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("MyLogTag", "Exception in getInternetData", e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any Exceptions?

Comment: to be honest, I'm not even sure where to see where the exception gets printed...I'm using eclipse...

Comment: It should be in your logcat. In your `catch`, change `e.PrintStackTrace()` to `Log.e("MyLogTag", "Exception in getInternetData", e)`. While `e.printStackTrace()` will work, the Android standard is to use `Log`. However, it appears this method is also throwing most of the Exception it creates, so you will want to ensure you are capturing and logging those Exceptions somewhere else as well.

Comment: No exceptions are being thrown which is making this more and more curious...

Comment: It also appears that it is not logging anything using that Log.e as I tried adding above the "try" and removing the "e" variable and it is not adding anything to the log....

Comment: Reading through the [logging guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) for more help with logging. Are you sure `getInternetData()` is being called at all? What happens if you put a breakpoint at the beginning of it?

Comment: Here is the code from the main java...note that the other class is called "GetMethodEx.java"

Comment: I have added the other code to the original post.  In the main class (HttpTest) it gets the results from getInternetData() and should put them in "returned" which then is put into the TextView....

Comment: If you put a call to `Log.d()` in `onCreate()`, do you see your log message? I think getting your logs will be the key to this issue.

Comment: @Tanis.7x, I just tried adding the Log.d() in my onCreate function however nothing showed up in the LogCat that I have open.  All it seems to be showing is my current battery state and Tethering status...

Comment: Did you read [the logging guide I linked to earlier](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)? Are you running your application using the debug icon in Eclipse or Android Studio? Do you have any filters set?

Comment: I am running using debug mode in Eclipse and I have a breakpoint set so I can see where it's going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, because 
you do network operations on the main Thread.
You either have to put this method into a new Thread, 
or you separate this code into a new Class which extends AsyncTask.
I would recommend to use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you call the requesting method asynchronously?
You may use the Android AsyncTask.